# Insurance options missing from Layouts in OpenEMR 5.0.0

Tags: php, mysql

I just recently got OpenEMR 5.0.0 running locally on my Mac to do some testing and I noticed that almost every single insurance-related field is required in order to create a new patient.

As I understand it, this should be configurable under Administration -> Layouts, but no insurance fields show up under any of the available options.

Everything else seems to work fine.  I am able, for example, to create appointments, generate reports, etc.

I am slowly plodding my way through the PHP code and the MySQL database, but if anyone has some higher-level solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here - which as far as I can tell is completely undocumented.

Fields can be specified as required, optional, or unused normally through the Administration -> Layouts forms, but there are no options there to change whether the insurance parameters are required or not.

Instead, what had happened is that the 5.0.0 distribution comes with a file new_comprehensive.php that sets every single form input related to insurance as a required field.

When I modified this file to not require the field to be filled out, naturally I was able to submit the form.

I saw in the HTML that the form fields were required, but I assumed they were set somewhere by PHP or JavaScript.  It turned out that they were all hardwired.